# Is one operation on two separate things singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

I have the following sentence:
"Burning fossil fuels like oil and gas is the main source of greenhouse gas emissions from human activities"

My question is whether I should use singular or plural ragarding the source? So an alternative would be:
"Burning fossil fuels like oil and gas are the main source of greenhouse gas emissions from human activities"

Comment: The correct option is **"is"**. "Burning fossil fuels like oil and gas is the main source of greenhouse gas emissions from human activities" . 'Is' refers to 'the process of burning of fossil fuels', which is singular so you should use 'is'.

Comment: Cool, thanks Decapitated Soul for your answer

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Please ***write an answer.*** I haven't found another question which would provide a duplicate target for this one. The title here probably needs improvement to help searchability though.

Comment: *Burning* — a gerund — functions as a noun and is the simple subject of your sentence. You can take out everything following it, up to the verb, to better see the agreement: _Burning **is** the main source of greenhouse gas emissions from human activities._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct option in this sentence is **"is"**.

"***Burning*** fossil fuels like [oil and gas] is the main source of greenhouse gas emissions from human activities".
**'Is'** refers to **'the process of burning of fossil fuels'**, which is singular.

If the sentence were *"burning **and [another process]** of fossil fuels like [oil and gas] **are** the main **sources** of greenhouse gas emission from human activities"*, you would use **are** because **'burning *and* [another process]'** is plural.